# Can a tablet dated to the reign of king Aha be deciphered?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-egypt

The following is an outline of the tablet showing the string by which it was attached to goods for shipment or storage.

[image]

Then comes the main source of information:
[image]

The first two glyphs are easy to decipher:
[image]
[image]

What about the rest of the glyphs?

Comment: Please include sources for any information and images used in questions (or answers). Improperly using information without proper citation can result in plagiarism flags and possible account suspensions.  It also helps any user to follow up on your question, and not repeat any research you have already done.

Comment: I did state that the information about the tablet is from a book by Flienders Petrie.
The research is mine and the images are ‘photographs’ of the pages of an article of mine.
By the way, I have my name misspelled “Trimnijopulos” instead of “Trimijopulos” but it seems that I am not allowed to update my profile.

Comment: Please cite the article fully, even if you are the owner. For instance if its a post on facebook, declare it as such, with a link to the original.

Comment: OK, will do. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

The legend on the tag reads:

> **[To] The judge in Mesquet chamber of Imiut, administrator of Horus' enclosure.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
In the scene of judgment from the papyrus of Hunefer, right below, so much god Anubis, at left holding Hunefer by the hand, as god Thoth in the right noting the verdict, wear an animal skin with the tail clearly shown trailing behind.
Most probably the skin kept on the pole was once the official dress of the judge and it was this skin the one kept into the Mesquet chamber.
The two Imiut poles in the tomb of Tutankhamen seem to suggest double judgment and, as a consequence,  high degree of purity.
It is almost certain that the second judgment took place in the West and that it was focused on examining the language and the loyalties of the person being judged. Yet, an Imiut skin used by the judge in the original judgment in the East, cannot be ruled out.
[image]
[image]
Jochem Kahl writes: “Due to the similarity of the triangle with a hieroglyph sign from the Old Kingdom, which represented a penis and a female genital organ, Günter Dreyer sees a vulva, in the small tablets from tomb Uj,  and thus a sign for the female, namely the Harim.
The sign "Hawk on Triangle" should therefore stand for the Harim of the King.”
[image]
[image]

The answer given comes from an article of mine titled “Deciphering a 5050-year-old Egyptian tablet”

Links to the original article:
[Academia.edu](https://www.academia.edu/38345632/Deciphering_a_5050_year_old_Egyptian_tablet)

[Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/Setbastet/posts/122305185829347)

Comment: Even if this work is yours (as it appears it may be) you still need to cite and reference it correctly, with author and publication (and a link if there is one possible). See the [Help on referencing](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). The reason is that links break, and answers get copied elsewhere with the text but without the link. Putting everything in text as well means that people don't have to click the link to see the source, and author information always goes with the article.

Comment: OK, Thanks!
I’ll add a note stating that the answer comes from an article of mine titled “Deciphering a 5050-year-old Egyptian tablet”